# How do you get a view reference from a class that doesn't extend Activity?

Tags: android, class, android-activity, extends

I want to have a class "Utils", that will have several methods used all over my code. For example, I have a top bar with a `textview` and two `ImageButton`s that must display different texts and icons on different activities.

I find myself writing stuff like this on every activity:

```
(TextView) topBarText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.topBarText);
topBarText.setText(R.id.mytextForThisView);
```

I'd like to findViewById once in my whole app, and call a method `setupTopBar(String text, R.id.iconForImageButton1, R.id.iconForImageButton2)`, or even pass the current Activity's id and let the method figure out what to show in the text and images.

I created the class `Util`, but it doesn't extend `Activity`. The problem is that if it doesn't, `findViewById` isn't accessible, so I can't use it.

What's the pattern to do something like this in Android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your helper methods should look like

```
public static void setTopBarText(Activity act, int textId){
    (TextView) topBarText = (TextView)act.findViewById(R.id.topBarText);
    topBarText.setText(textId);
}
```

Then you can do a static import from Activity and call

```
setTopBarText(this, R.id.mytextForThisView);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is not good for some situation.

This is my method:

```
In your Activity:
YouCustomClassObject.passView((View)findViewById(R.id.aview));
```

Using parameter passing can solve this kind of problem.